# How to convert parameters to the desired type in a function that requires parameters of a certain type and uses pointers

Tags: c, pointers

In the book I am reading, there is an example of code

```
int compare_parts (const void *p, const void *q)
{
  struct part *p1 = p;
  struct part *q1 = q;
```

This code is part of a comparison function for qsort. The book says that since qsort requires parameters of type `void *`, and we can't access part numbers through void pointers, we need pointers to part structures. It says that to solve the problem, we have made `compare_parts` assign p and q to variables of type `struct part *`, thereby converting them to the desired type.

This doesn't make sense to me. In my mind, the line `struct part *p1 = p` means that p1 points to p. And p must point to *p by the definition of the indirection operator. Therefore, p1 points to p points to *p. And `struct part *p1 = p` tells us that p1 points to an object with type `struct part`, therefore p must have type `struct part`, since p1 points to p. But how can p have type `struct part` if it is a pointer? I would expect it to point to something with type `struct part`, but not to have this type itself.

Comment: "In my mind, the line `struct part *p1 = p` means that p1 points to p"

It doesn't mean that. It means "initialize the pointer `p1` with the value of `p`". There's no additional indirection, `p` is already a pointer and `p1` simply points to the same thing as `p`, but with a different type.

Comment: `p` is a variable, not an object it points to. So the variable `p` of type `void*` can point to an object of type `struct part`. The `void` is an incompleted type so `p` cannot be dereferenced. Firstly, it must be cast to a completed type.

Comment: After `struct part *p1 = p;` both `p1` and `p` are pointing to the exact same location. I'ts like `int i = 5; int i1 = i;` Now both `i` and `i1` have the same value.

Comment: You are just confused about pointer initialization. Try something simpler to understand the concept. For example, `int i; int *j=&i; int *k=j; /* now k==j */`. After that, try to understand `int i; void* j=i; int* k=j;`.

Comment: @Cubic I don't understand. I would have thought that to initialise p1 with the value of p, the code would be `p1 = p`. `*p1 = p` sounds to me like the thing p1 is pointing to (*p1) is being initialised with the value of p.

Comment: It's a *declaration*, the asterisk `*` is part of the *type*, not a dereference operator. If we rewrite it to `struct part* p1 = p;` would it make it simpler? It's *exactly* the same, but now it might be clearer that the asterisk belongs to the type and not the variable.

Comment: @Urthona26 you're reading it wrong. It's not `*p1 = p`, it's `struct part* p1 = p`. Meaning, "declare a variable of type `struct part*` (i.e. pointer to `struct part`) and initialize its value with `p`)"

Comment: This is the same as writing `struct part *p1; p1 = p;`. I think you're confusing this with `struct part *p1; *p1 = p`.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I thought that might be the answer, but I wasn't sure. So, just to confirm, if a variable v points to an object with type `struct part`, we would say that v has type `struct part *` even though v is a pointer, and wouldn't say that *v has type `struct part`, which is what I would have said before. Is that correct?

Comment: It's OK to say the *expression* `*v` has type `struct part`. You just need to understand that `int *p1=p2` is not the same as `*p1=p2`. In the former case the asterisk is part of the syntax you use to declare a variable. In the latter it is an operator.

Comment: In this code really taken as-is from a book? Which book? Because it isn't valid C.

Comment: @Lundin I'd tell you but it's an American book and I know from films that they like to sue people over there.

Comment: Unless you stole it I don't see why they would sue you for saying it is bad... it's rather the publisher who'd risk a lawsuit by you for false marketing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct part *p1 = p;` does not contain an assignment `*p1 = p;`. The grammar for initializations was added to C after the initial grammar for declarations was created.

In `struct part *p1 = p;`, `struct part *p1` declares `p1` to be a pointer to a `struct part`, and the `= p` says to initialize `p1` with the value of `p`.

The initialization in a declaration always initializes just the plain object being declared, the `p1`, not any expression that could be formed with the other parts in the declarator.

Answer (score 1):

> `struct part *p1 = p` means that p1 points to p.

No it doesn't or it would have been written as `= &p`. This line is supposed to copy the pointer's contents to another pointer. A common beginner mistake is to confuse pointer declarations with pointer de-referencing: `struct part *p1` does *not* de-reference anything, it just declares a pointer. Whereas the line `*p1 = p;` without a pointer type declaration would mean de-referencing.

There is a rule in C saying that any pointer to an object may get converted to a `void*` and back, and then compare equal to the original address.

In case of `qsort` you originally have an array of `struct part` objects. Internally, `qsort` passes on pointers to array items from this array to the `compare` callback function, which is why it is fine to convert those pointers back to the pointer to struct type and then de-reference it.

---

However, the code posted is invalid C. The rules of initialization/assignment (C17 6.5.16.1) say that this must hold true:

> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

What this "standard gibberish" means in this case is:

In case either `p1` or `p` is a `void*` and the other is a pointer to an object type such as `struct part*`, then this is a valid assignment/initialization, *but only* if the left operand `p1` has all "qualifiers" (`const` etc) as the right operand. (The left one may however have qualifiers that the right one lacks - we can always add qualifiers during assignment but never remove them.)

This is not the case here, you did not write `const struct part* p1` and therefore you cannot assign `p` to it. This is a "contraint violation" and the compiler must report it with a message.

If you found this code in a book, then that book might be of questionable quality since it would then suggest that they haven't even tried to compile the examples.